# Android+LibGDX - textures gone in Android UI activity only after finishing a Libgdx activity?

Tags: android, user-interface, textures, libgdx

My situation is this:

- I have 3 activities: 2 using Android UIs (shown below) and 1 a Libgdx AndroidApplication
- I can go back and forth from my 2 menu activities all I want and it is WAI
- I can go to my Libgdx AndroidApplication from my a Menu activity and it is WAI
- I can go back to my Menu activites from my Libgdx AndroidApplication, and for a split second I have fonts/etc. rendering as they should, but then they quickly turn into this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtoCb.jpg

My hypothesis is that the libgdx AndroidApplication when destroyed must be freeing / unloading, or instructing Android to, texture memory or a GL Surface view or some texture memory backing that Android fonts are using?

The NinePatch drawables for the buttons are even being affected so its not a font-specific thing.  The On/Off switch is not though, for that I am assigning the drawable to it in-code.

Perhaps the layout inflater for setContentView thinks its textures are loaded when they are actually being freed by Libgdx activity's onDestroy?

P.S. At first I thought I was just out of memory so the fonts couldn't be loaded into texture, meaning I had a fat memory leak somewhere, but Memory analysis indicates I am leak free.   This image is after going back and forth through all 3 activities 5 times:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/45aev.jpg

Any help? I'm so lost on this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I may have solved my problem unintentionally, it may have been due to a memory leak after all.

I was passing enabled ListView items from an activity to the libgdx activity (the item object backings themselves, not the list view item 'views').  I knew the ListView was holding onto them, but the item object themselves I used as extras were a simple container of Strings and booleans, no references to contexts or listviews.  In any case, this was an Android issue, not so much a Libgdx problem.